# Using the multi query function to modify table after clear button is clicked

Tags: php, mysql

$DBConnect = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password")

$query = "DELETE FROM hitcounter";

$query = "ALTER TABLE hitcounter AUTO_INCREMENT=0";

if (isset($_POST['clear']))

{

(mysqli_multi_query($DBConnect,$query))

// I made a hit counter which displays hits on page

// Only thing i have left is the reset button that switch the pages hits to 0 after the clear button is pressed

// I am unable to execute the query

}

Comment: ignoring the mistakes you made in your query variable declaration i advice you to use `TRUNCATE TABLE hitcounter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$query = "TRUNCATE TABLE hitcounter;"
```

Which will delete all rows and reset the auto_increment to 0 as well in only one query.

**EDIT:**

This does not work for InnoDB tables as long they have a relationship

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. it is much more efficient than executing the two queries.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what error you are getting, but you need to change your PHP code as follows:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM hitcounter;";

$query .= "ALTER TABLE hitcounter AUTO_INCREMENT=0;";
```

The first query needs a terminating ; and the second line should append to the string. As written it will over write. So the only statement that executes is the ALTER TABLE.

This will fix your code problem regarding multi-queries, but as others have noted, using `TRUNCATE TABLE` is better for the job

Comment: That's probably because of the missing ; at the end of the `(mysqli_multi_query($DBConnect,$query))`. You also don't need the outer set of ( ) and you should capture the return value to check for errors.

Comment: Ok thanks i added the ; and i didn't get an error but i don't think the query was executed. I am making a hitcounter webpage that counts hits on a webpage and includes a clear button. The clear button after being clicked should change the value of the hits to 0.

Comment: You should follow the advice from the other answer and switch to TRUNCATE and a sinle query. It's better.